# C# / WCF: Populate and Consume ServiceInterface through Metadata Endpoint

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I got a service which offers a named pipe as connection point/endpoint address for 3rd party applications.

what i did so far is:

```
Uri[] baseAddress = new Uri[]{
new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")};

string PipeName = "Calculator";

serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(CalculatorImplementation), baseAddress);

// Add a mex endpoint 
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/CalculatorServer");
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), PipeName);

serviceHost.Open();
```

I'm connecting in my client using a ChannelFactory like this:

```
ChannelFactory<ICalculator> pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<ICalculator>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/Calculator"));

ICalculator pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
```

But acutally I wonder if there is a more "usual" way to connect to the service. 
Does I really need to tell every 3rd party app the "connection string"/Endpoint Address of my named pipe ("net.pipe://localhost/Calculator") ?

I thought that there might be a better way to accomplish this, but I did not found a way to do this so far.

I created already that "mex endpoint" but I'm not sure how to use this endpoint to populate the named pipe.

My questions are: 
I'm populating the service interface the right way?
and
How do I use the Metadata Endpoint in a client application right?

Comment: "Can somebody help me to get my feet on the ground in this issue?" This is much too broad.  Ask a more specific question and then if you have more questions, make new questions.

Comment: of cause ... thanks for that hint